# Como ejecutar un formulario C# con OpenFileDialog desde un html?

Tags: c#, html5

A continuación anexo un ejemplo de código *html* en donde requiero saber como puedo mandar ejecutar un formulario que tiene un objeto `OpenFileDialog` para buscar y cargar un archivo con extensión *.csv*; la parte donde deseo incrustarlo la resalto con asteriscos(*).

Si tienen una idea más fácil y sencilla de cargar un archivo desde este *html* también es muy bien recibida.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Front.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WishList.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="WishListPage" Title="WishList" %>

<%@ Register Src="Components/Message.ascx" TagName="Message" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Vevo" %>
<asp:Content ID="uxContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="uxPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
    <div class="WishList">
        <uc1:Message ID="uxMessage" runat="server" NumberOfNewLines="1"></uc1:Message>
        <div class="CommonPage">
            <div class="CommonPageTop">
                <asp:Image ID="uxTopLeft" ImageUrl="~/Images/Design/Box/DefaultBoxTopLeft.gif" runat="server"
                    CssClass="CommonPageTopImgLeft" />
                <asp:Label ID="uxDefaultTitle" runat="server" CssClass="CommonPageTopTitle">[$Wish List]</asp:Label>
                <asp:Image ID="uxTopRight" ImageUrl="~/Images/Design/Box/DefaultBoxTopRight.gif"
                    runat="server" CssClass="CommonPageTopImgRight" />
                <div class="Clear">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="CommonPageLeft">
                <div class="CommonPageRight">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="uxWishListPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                        <asp:GridView ID="uxWishListGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID,Options,CartItemID"
                            CssClass="CommonGridView WishListGridView" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None"
                            OnRowDeleting="uxWishListGrid_RowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="uxWishListGrid_RowUpdating">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="ImageItemDiv">
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="uxItemImageLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# GetURL( Container.DataItem ) %>'>
                                                <asp:Image ID="uxItemImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetItemImage( Container.DataItem ) %>'
                                                    Width="60" />
                                            </asp:HyperLink></div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="ImageHeader" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="ImageItem" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="[$Name]" SortExpression="Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="uxNameLink" runat="server" Text='<%# GetName( Container.DataItem ) %>'
                                            NavigateUrl='<%# GetURL( Container.DataItem ) %>' CssClass="CommonHyperLink"></asp:HyperLink>
                                        </asp:HyperLink>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="NameItem" />
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="NameHeader" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="[$Unit Price]" SortExpression="Price">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="uxLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# GetUnitPriceText( Container.DataItem ) %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="PriceItem" />
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="PriceHeader" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="[$Quantity]" SortExpression="Quantity">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                 <asp:Label ID="uxQuantityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>' CssClass="Quantity" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="QuantityItem" />
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="QuantityHeader" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                 <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="uxAddToCartButton" runat="server" Text="[$BtnWishListAddToCart]"
                                            CssClass="BtnStyle1" CommandName="Update" Visible='<%# CheckWebsiteMode() %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="AddToCartHeader" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="AddToCartItem" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Del">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="uxDeleteImageButton" runat="server" Text="[$BtnDelete]" CssClass="ButtonDelete"
                                            CommandName="Delete" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="DeleteHeader" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="DeleteItem" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="uxEmptyMessageLabel" runat="server" Text="[$NoData]"></asp:Label>
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <FooterStyle CssClass="CommonGridViewHeaderStyle WishListGridViewFooterStyle" />
                            <RowStyle CssClass="CommonGridViewRowStyle WishListGridViewRowStyle" />
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="CommonGridViewHeaderStyle WishListGridViewViewHeaderStyle" />
                            <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="CommonGridViewEmptyRowStyle" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <div class="WishListButtonDiv" id="uxButtonDiv" runat="server">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="uxContinueButton" runat="server" Text="[$BtnWishListContinueShopping]"
                                OnClick="uxContinueButton_Click" CssClass="WishListContinueImageButton" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="uxViewShoppingCartButton" runat="server" Text="[$BtnViewShoppingCart]"
                                OnClick="uxViewShoppingCartButton_Click" CssClass="WishListViewShoppingCartImageButton BtnStyle2" />
                        </div>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="CommonPageBottom">
                <asp:Image ID="uxBottomLeft" ImageUrl="~/Images/Design/Box/DefaultBoxBottomLeft.gif"
                    runat="server" CssClass="CommonPageBottomImgLeft" />
                <asp:Image ID="uxBottomRight" ImageUrl="~/Images/Design/Box/DefaultBoxBottomRight.gif"
                    runat="server" CssClass="CommonPageBottomImgRight" />
                <div class="Clear">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="uxStatusHidden" runat="server" />
    </div>

****************************************************************************
<%--   AQUI QUIERO LLAMAR AL Form1.cs QUE TIENE UN OpenFileDialog PARA PODER BUSCAR UN ARCHIVO DE CARGA CON EXTENSION .csv --%>
****************************************************************************

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: entiendo estas utilizando asp.net, peor no lo pusiste como etiqueta, en cambio defines html5 que no veo tenga relacion

Comment: No se puede mezclar ASP.NET con WinForms. Lo unico que puedes usar para hacer el upload como quieres es el control mismo de asp: <asp:fileupload> Mas info aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Esta claro que tiene problemas conceptuales relacionados a lo que un desarrollo web implica. Recuerda que no puedes hacer uso de componentes winform en un desarrollo asp.net, por lo tanto el OpenFileDialog no aplica, lo mismo sucede con el MessageBox, etc.

Los archivo que puedes seleccionar estaran en el cliente y lo elegir usando el control `FileUpload`

[Cómo: Cargar archivos con el control FileUpload de servidor Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms227669(v=vs.100).aspx)

el usuario visualizara un dialogo para buscar el archivo dentro de su discos local. La idea es que se realice un submit del archivo al servidor.

Comment: Hola, agradezco mucho tus comentarios y respuesta, recibe un cordial saludo.